# Python code, .rstrip isn't working?

Tags: python, uppercase, strip

I've searched answers on here and tried implementing them but I think that there is some tiny detail I'm missing. I have a very short python code for a program that is supposed to return the initials with periods of a persons input(for their full name). So for example, input is Atticus Leonard Beasley and output should be

```
A.L.B.
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
A.
L.
B.
```

Here's my code:

```
def main():

    full_name = input("Enter your first, middle, and last name: ")

    for ch in full_name:
        if ch.isupper():
            ch = ch.rstrip('\n')
            print (ch,'.', sep='')

main()
```

Comment: If `ch` is `'A'`, what are you expecting `'A'.strip('\n')` to be?

Comment: `for ch in full_name` should never have a `\n` as `ch` as the `input` takes all input up to the newline

Comment: I think you're over-complicating things. These are the steps you need: split the input using `split`, use indexing to get the first character of each word, use `'.'.join` to join these together

Comment: Use `end=''` in your `print` call.

Comment: Thank you Mark Dickinson, that worked exactly how I needed it to!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can do this using `split` and `join`:

```
def main():

    full_name = input("Enter your first, middle, and last name: ")
    initials = []

    for name in full_name.split():
        initials.append(name[0])

    print('.'.join(initials) + '.')

main()
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
def main():

    full_name = input("Enter your first, middle, and last name: ")
    print('.'.join(name[0] for name in full_name.split())+'.')

main()
```

Comment: You forgot to add `.split()` function to full_name in the list comprehension example.

Comment: @MaxChrétien Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in a easier and "more pythonic" way.

```
full_name = input("Enter your first, middle, and last name: ")

print(''.join([ch[0].upper() + '.' for ch in full_name.split()]))
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

Instead of doing a `for` loop over each letters of the name, you can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to be sure to took care of every words without the extra spaces.

```
sentence = "hello world"

for ch in sentence.split():
    print(ch) # hello
    break
```

Now, you try to verify if the first letter is an `uppercase`, but if the user enter his name without `uppercase`, your function does not work. An easier solution will be to extract the first letter of the word `ch[0]` and automatically add an `uppercase`: `ch[0].upper()`

Maybe the one-liner solution is confusing, but most of the python developers use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)  over `for` loops when the solution is easily readable.

**EDIT**

One more thing, even if you are writing a simple function such as print the initials of a name, you should *always* write tests accordingly.

A good way to start is to use [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#module-doctest) because it forces you to describe what your function does. Even if you think it's a waste of times, it helps to overcome many problems when your program is getting bigger. I'd be please to help you if you want to try to write your first `doctest`